# Applet will not display when run in a browser

Tags: java, browser, applet

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <applet code="game/Game" name="Game" archive="Game.jar" width="800" height="600">
    No java support.
    </applet>
</body>
```

I'm currently trying to run the above html code in a web browser in order to display my java applet game. The html file is in the same directory as the jar file. What happens when I open the html page is that it asks me if I want to trust the applet (which I just digitally signed myself), and when I say yes, it just displays a blank screen. Also, my CPU usage increases noticeably, so I imagine something is getting stuck.

I can run my applet in Eclipse with no problems. Furthermore, I realize the `applet` tag is deprecated, however I'm not looking to make this too complicated, plus I need it to run on computers with very outdated browsers.
So, what could the reasons be that my applet will not display? I receive no errors/exceptions, it just shows a white area where my applet should be. Also, when I put the mouse over that area, the cursor does change to what it would be if it were over an applet.

EDIT: Interestingly enough, I was clicking around on the white area where the applet should be, and managed to make one of my in applet menu texts come up. I'm thinking that maybe my images are just not showing up. Why might this be the case?

Comment: Does anything show up in the Java console?

Comment: There is no java console when I run it in the browser

Comment: You should be able to open one by right-clicking on a Java applet.

Comment: Nothing happens when I right click on the applet

Comment: If you refer to my edit, I now believe that images are simply not showing up in the applet.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.